# edit.php alter links

Tags: wp-admin, post-editor

I want to alter the view of edit.php in the posts admin area. What I want is when a category is set ( $_GET['cat'], cat=x in the url ), add post would be post-new.php?cat=x.

Is this possible?

I know there is a sample code on wordpress answers that gives you this ability, but it does not alter the Add Post / Add Page link on the edit.php screen. I've managed to do this by hacking the edit.php myself, but normally in the next update all changes will be lost.

here is a picture depicting what needs to be altered....

[image]

Comment: It's not quite clear what do you intend to accomplish by altering links?

Comment: Trying to add automatically the category on new post/page/custom post once a user has selected it from the category select box (wp 3.8.1). So far I can only do it by altering the core edit.php file.

Comment: Pretty sure I answered question exactly like this in the past, but shoot me I can't find it... :(

Comment: I'd be very interested if you find that :) The reason is that I am making a dashboard panel for editors so that they would edit specific items (which have been stripped of custom fields and wpml panels) in the cms admin (simplified admin options).

Comment: Ok, hadn't found mine, but found even better. :) See linked Q.

Comment: Almost, but no cigar... I've found the question before, but it does not alter the original "Add New" link.

Comment: Ok, I am confused now. :) Please elaborate on your question with more details and some examples, it's too short in this form.

Comment: I've put an image showing what I am trying to do with the links.